# Triggered Send - passing nested data

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, email, json, data

Is there any good solution for sending nested (not flat) data to triggered send?

Suppose I want to send a transaction confirmation email. Ideally, I would like to send a json (or json-like) object like this one (every transaction can have many payment details and translations):

```
{
    "transaction":{
        "number":"...",
        "recipient":{
            "name":"John Smith",
            "country":{
                "name":"Colombia"
            },
        },
        "sender":{
            "name":"Jane Smith"
        },
        "payment_details":[
            {
                "name":"Amount payable:",
                "value":"€101.00"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "translations":
        "subject":"Translated subject",
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it directly. But I haven't found anything like it in the documentation, so I assume it's not possible.

So far I came up with 2 solutions:

1. Create a separate data extension for every nested structure (For example 'Translations' DE: email_id, key, value). But this will require to add a lot of records for every email we send.
2. Create a long text attribute with xml and parse this xml using AMPscript, as described here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/passing_content_to_a_triggered_send_message_at_send_time/. But that seems hacky and error-prone. I'm also worried about the length of the text field. Is there any limit? Xml is very verbose.

Is there any better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should send an XML payload to your trigger and then use an XSLT to transform it using the [TransformXML()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/TransformXML.html) AMPSCript function in your email template.

The XSLT files are stored in the Portfolio.

One link tracking gotcha with XSLTs -- you'll need to have ET/SFMC Support enable the `WRAP_HTTPGET_URLS` business rule with a `Quality` of `99` and prefix the links in your XML file  with `httpgetwrap|` so they get properly tracked.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Adam's recommendation.  You can pass the hierarchical data as an additional attribute in your trigger call.  You need to add a text field to the triggered send data extension the trigger writes in order to capture this information. Alternatively, you could add an list attribute to store this data.  But, I would recommend the data extension route. Storing in a list attribute would require that you overwrite the value each time the trigger is called for the same subscriber.

Comment: p.s.  be sure to encode the XML payload or use <![CDATA]> to prevent any parsing issues by the Soap API.

Comment: p.s.s You could just as easily pass the payload as JSON.  However, email ampscript language has functions for parsing XML.  But, does not have similar functions for processing JSON.